# Linking my program using g++

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have some problems to build a program using g++. The program is using a library that I have written in C called libiec60063. I want to write my new project in C++ (even if not yet familiar with C++) but I can't manage to link it correctly.

For example I have the following code in a file called main.cpp

```
#include <libiec60063.h>

int main() {
    Select_IEC60063_Number(125, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile the source correctly typing

```
g++ -I/home/workspace/a_CommonBinary/include -c main.cpp
```

If I want to link it i get some error message

```
g++ -L/home/workspace/a_CommonBinary_draft/lib -o main main.o -lm -liec60063
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `Select_IEC60063_Number(double, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I rename the main-file to main.c I can compile and link the program correctly with the GCC-Compiler using the same parameters.

Can anybody explain where there is a difference between gcc and g++?

Comment: Are you sure this library have specified function? What is the output of `nm -D /path/to/your/libiec60063.so | grep Select_IEC60063_Number`?

Comment: Add the source(`.c` or `.cpp` file), object(`.o`) or library (`.lib` or `.so`) file that contains `Select_IEC60063_Number` function.

Comment: `nm -D /path/to/your/libiec60063.so | grep Select_IEC60063_Number`
returns
`00000c10 T Select_IEC60063_Number`

Comment: Is libiec60063 a C library or a C++ library ? in case it's a C library, perhaps they didn't guard their libiec60063.h header for use in C++ code - so you'd have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to put

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif
```

near the beginning of your `libiec60063.h` header file, and

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }; // end extern "C"
 #endif
```

near the end of your header file, or if you don't want to change the header file:

```
extern "C" {
#include  <libiec60063.h>
};
```

in your C++ code.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/841108). You need to disable [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Read about [compatibility of C & C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) .

BTW, you should compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and perhaps with `-std=c++11` and code for [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

Comment: It's probably not OP's library, so wrapping `extern` around `#include` is also an option.

Comment: The OP writes: The program is using a library that *I have written in C* called libiec60063